# How to test if a finite extension contains any zero of an irreducible polynomial?

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, extension-field

So specifically, if $E/F$ is a finite extension of degree $n$ and $f\in F[x]$ if an irreducible of degree dividing $n$, then is it always true that all zeros of $f$ falls into $E$ ?
If $E=GF(q^n)$ is finite, then $F(a)=GF(q)(a)\cong GF(q^k), k|n, f(a)=0$ but how does it implies that $F(a)\subseteq E$ ? I mean, just because it is isomorphic to a subfield of $E$ doesn't mean that it is a subfield of $E$, right ?

Comment: Are you asking about finite fields $F$ specifically, or about general fields?

Comment: I am asking about finite field specifically, it'd be even better if the general case is provided though.

Answer (score 1):

In field theory, or more generally in abstract algebra, we are interested in algebraic structures *up to isomorphism*. So yes technically $F(a)$ may not exactly be a subfield of $E$, but it is isomophic to a subfield of $E$ so we say that $F(a) \subseteq E$. Only the field structure is interesting in that case.

Your question is true for finite field, as there is only one field of order $q^n$ up to isomorphism and $\mathbb{F}_{q^k} \subseteq \mathbb{F}_{q^n}$ if and only if $k \mid n$. In your example, if $f$ is irreducible of degree $k$, all the zeroes of $f$ lies in $\mathbb{F}_{q^k} \subseteq \mathbb{F}_{q^n}$.

In general, this is completely false. For example $[\mathbb{Q}[i] \ : \ \mathbb{Q}]=2$ and $f(x)=x^2-2$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ but $\mathbb{Q}[i]$ contains no roots of $f$. The real problem here is that there is infinitely many field extensions of degree $n$ whereas there is only one degree $n$ extension of $\mathbb{F}_q$.

Comment: Hi, I meant that, if we are given $GF(q)\subseteq GF(q^n)$ **beforehand**, for a degree $k$ irreducible $f(x)$, even if $GF(q)(a)\cong GF(q^k)\subseteq GF(q^n)$, we still cannot claim that there's some element $b$ being a zero of $f(x)$. I think it is esentially different things.

Comment: I'm not really sure to follow, but if $a$ if a root of $f$ and $\phi \ : \mathbb{F}_q(a) \to \mathbb{F}_{q^k}$ is an isomorphism, then $\phi(a)$ is a root of $f$. As I said, in that case you can consider two isomorphic fields to be equal in some sense.

Comment: Oh, I think the argument that $a$ sits within $F_{q^n}$ is true. And it seems sufficient to just show that $a\in F_{q^n}$, isn't it?

Comment: Yes all the roots of $f$ will lie in $\mathbb{F}_{q^n}$.

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't clear to me from the question that our OP Taylor Huang's main interest lay with finite fields, so I cooked up this counterexample:

I don't think this is true in general:

Take $F = \Bbb Q$ and $E = \Bbb Q(\sqrt[3] 2)$; then

$[E:F] = [\Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]2): \Bbb Q] =3; \tag 1$

now take

$f(x) = x^3 - 2 \in \Bbb Q[x]; \tag 2$

then $f(x)$ is irreducible over $\Bbb Q$, $\deg f(x) \mid [E:F]$, but $f(x)$ has precisely one zero in $E = \Bbb Q(\sqrt[3] 2)$.

Comment: My bad for not clarify that my interest mainly lay with finite field. Could you please extend your answer to also finite field? Thanks.